# Restful routing with different controllers for the same resource resolving the "wrong" url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a Store model. And two controllers:

- stores_controller
- admin/stores_controller

now in the list view of the admin/stores_controller I am trying to generate a link to the destroy action in the admin/stores_controller but every variation I have tried either goes to the stores_controller (so not the admin one) or to some other incorrect url.

I am currenty using

```
<%= link_to "Delete", :controller => "admin/stores", 
            :action => "destroy", :id => store, :method => :delete %>
```

but this generates a url like http://localhost:3000/admin/stores/5?method=delete which invokes the show action instead of the destroy one.

in routes.rb I have

```
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.resources :stores
end

map.resources :stores
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a namespace, use `link_to` like so:

```
link_to 'Show', [:admin, @var]
```

Similarly, if you want to reference a form:

```
form_for([:admin, @var])
```

etc.